# How to escape single quote for t

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace `t` to `t'`.

Since \t returns a tab, I can't really do `\t\’`.
I've also tried doing \047, \47, \27 etc. but it returns error, I am assuming due to the backslashes since I'm using `sed` i.e. `sed "s/t/t\047/"`

How can I give `t` a single quote without them tabbing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed "s/t/t'/"` works for me (remember to add `g` if you want to replace all `t`s in a line):

```
$ sed "s/t/t'/" <<<"football"
foot'ball
```